# awk print only results after X time

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to make a script that prints the procceses that start after the script is launched.

The script

```
a=$(date +"%T")
while true
    do
        b=$(ps -eo pid,lstart,cmd | awk '{print $1,$5,$7}')
        log=$(awk -v A=$a '{ for (i=A; i<=NF; i++)  } ' <<< $b)
        echo $b
        sleep 2
        clear
    done
```

Im stuck with how to format awk to do the job

EDIT: nvm, i made it

```
time=$(date +"%T")
date=$(date +"%e")
while true
    do
        b=$(ps -eo pid,lstart,cmd | awk -v A="$time" -v B="$date" '{ if ( A <= $5 && B <= $4 ) print $1,$4,$5,$7;}')
        echo "$b"
        sleep 2
        clear
    done
```

The print of the script is

```
10969 6 13:02:19 /usr/bin/python3
10979 6 13:02:23 bash
10980 6 13:02:23 ps
10981 6 13:02:23 awk
```

as those are the only running procceses AFTER the script

Comment: Double quote the variables that may contain whitespace

Comment: Why call awk twice, once to populate `b` and then using `b` to populate `log`? Just pipe the `ps` output to 1 awk script.

Comment: you're right, was just too vague to change it since at start i made it like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made the script like this

```
time=$(date +"%T")
date=$(date +"%e")
while true
    do
        b=$(ps -eo pid,lstart,cmd | awk -v A="$time" -v B="$date" '{ if ( A <= $5 && B <= $4 ) print $1,$4,$5,$7;}')
        echo "$b"
        sleep 2
        clear
    done
```

The output is

```
10969 6 13:02:19 /usr/bin/python3
10979 6 13:02:23 bash
10980 6 13:02:23 ps
10981 6 13:02:23 awk
```